# Product image cache remove and regenerate live on frontend - M2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, image, magento2.3.5

At the moment we have many old product image cache url's on the frontend, with all 404 errors.

We can run the `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` command to regenerate them, but we have more than 270.000 images, so this will takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to clear the cache and regenerate the images directly on the frontend, when the product/categorypage is loaded for example? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello JGeer,**

Have a look this extension https://shop.dolphinwebsolution.com/catalog-image-resizer-for-magento.html

Maybe it'll fulfill your requirement.